# Problem with Icon react native Expo using fcm icon notifications

Tags: php, expo, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I'm trying to make my notification icon look correctly when I receive it on my cell phone.
I have tried adding in my app.json.
My image is .png and has a white background and blue lettering text.
I also tried to send it from my api made in php with Guzzle.

Assuming that the icon exists in the root of the React Native project. I also tried pointing to a route within the api with the image and it didn't work either.
Testing from Fire Base Console, it is also displayed erroneously.
Could someone tell me where the problem is? I attach my app.json.

```
  "expo": {
    "name": "ISSUNNE",
    "slug": "ISSUNNE",
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/issunne_new2.png",
    "notification":{
      "icon": "./assets/issunne_new2.png"
   },
    "userInterfaceStyle": "automatic",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/issunneico.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "buildNumber": "1.0.1",
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "requireFullScreen": true,
      "icon": "./assets/issunneico_lanzamiento.png",
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.kloud97.ISSUNNE"
    },
    "android": {
      "icon": "./assets/issunne_new2.png",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "versionCode": 4,
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/issunneico_lanzamiento.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.kloud97.ISSUNNE"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "XXXX"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

App Icon is:[App icon is 72x72 background transparent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnLhz.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTf9p.jpg)

How it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4E98.jpg
I have tried adding in my app.json.
Rebuild the app with 'eas build --profile development --platform android' then 'expo start --dev-client'.
I tried to send it from my api in PHP .

````
        'to' => $request->FCM,
        'notification' => [
            'title' => 'Test custom 2',
            'body' => 'das',
            'icon' => './assets/issunne_new2.png',
         
            "image"=> "https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ionicons/512/icon-camera-512.png"
             

        ],
    ];```
Nothing worked.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4E98.jpg
````